# Not display in XML unset BigDecimal

Tags: java, xml

I have a business requirement which I can't figure out.  I have a java class wherein I initialize currency values using BigDecimal such as this.

```
public class EncounterCharge {

    BigDecimal TotalCharge = new BigDecimal(0);
```

And I have a getter and setter.  The Setter is String and the getter returns BigDecimal

```
/**
 * @return the totalCharge
 */
@XmlElement(name = "TotalCharge")
public BigDecimal getTotalCharge() {
    return TotalCharge;
}
/**
 * @param totalCharge the totalCharge to set
 */
public void setTotalCharge(String totalCharge) {
    TotalCharge = new BigDecimal(totalCharge).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

The issue is, the business wants unset BigDecimal values to not appear in the XML.  Currently it does such as this `<totalCharges>0</totalCharges>.`  We don't want this to appear at all.  However, if it's explicitly set to 0, that's okay.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I can do something like initialize it to 0.001 and check (somehow) if the value is 0.001 and not do the XML if it's that value.  That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: What if  `totalCharges` is `null`, does it get rendered in the XML?

Comment: Yes, this the solution.  I'll add it.  TY!

Comment: I've undeleted my comment with explanation as to why it works. Thanks for confirming my statement.

Comment: I got the question wrong, therefore removing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Annotate it with [`@XmlTransient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html)</strike>. If you need the field populated, you will have to set the value to null. This is because `@XmlElement`, by default, has a `required` state to `false` so it ignores a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

As Buhake said, if you set the totalCharges to null it works fine.  Use the setter to set it to BigDecimal.

`@XmlTransient` is for not including fields but its not conditional.  Here we want to not include the field if it is not initialized.

Here's another tutorial about XMLTransient.  Thanks all.

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html